# What are the allowed languages for questions, comments or answers here?

Tags: discussion, faq, languages

Since Hinduism is spread all over the world, different people following different languages have their own ideas, doubts and opinions. And in Hinduism various concepts are explained and brought to the common man via Slokas, poems, and verses of various languages such as Sanskrit, Tamil, Telugu and more. With consideration to all these points, what are all the languages that are permitted here?

Comment: @Mr.Alien This is the original and the one you have specified is the duplicate! Check the date. :)

Comment: @Dharmaputhiran Yes sir, I did retracted my vote but forgot to delete the comment, I realized that after I cast a duplicate vote, hence later I voted the other question as a duplicate of this one, thanks for pinging, removed the comment now

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is an English-language site. Our posts **must primarily be in English**.

Now, of course, one may quote from texts in any other language, like Sanskrit or Tamil, but it would be best if an English translation was also provided alongside them.

Many users here do not speak English as a first language. That's totally fine - just do your best to write an answer in English, and other users here will help you fix up any errors present.