# Please provide transliterations for non-English text in your posts

Tags: discussion, post-quality, languages

Since this is [an English-language site](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/57/13), we should try to avoid assuming that people can read languages other than English. As such, if you are including text from another language (Sanskrit, etc.) in your post, it is nice to provide a transliteration. So, rather than posting this (from [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/286/13)):

> ...is considered devil/daemon (दानव) Vivaha (marriage) which isn't righteous (धर्मानुकूलन).

Post this:

> ...is considered devil/daemon (दानव *dānava*) Vivaha (marriage) which isn't righteous (धर्मानुकूलन *dharmānukūlana*).

---

If you don't know how to transliterate text from another language to English, here is an easy solution:

1. Go to [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/).
2. In the text box on the left, type or paste the text you want to transliterate.
3. From the list of languages available above the text box, select the language you want to transliterate from. For Sanskrit, select "Hindi" instead.
4. The transliterated form of the text will appear below that textbox. Copy it back into your question or answer here.

[image: how to get transliterations from Google Translate]

Google Translate may not be perfect, but it works pretty darned well.

Answer (score 6):

Good idea. But the problem I see with providing transliteration for each and every Sanskrit verse is that answers may get extremely long especially if you are citing a dozen verses.

Also, people who are used to reading Hindi or Devanagari script may find it tedious to provide transliteration when they have already provided the English translation.

But for those who don't mind doing it, I found a great transliteration tool here: https://www.ashtangayoga.info/sanskrit/transliteration/transliteration-tool

[Example](https://www.ashtangayoga.info/sanskrit/transliteration/transliteration-tool#devanagari/iast/xn--%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%7C%7C%7C%7C%0A-u17admb73bolbblaamu6eecccecbg5dd7ixbwek3brcctmda9g6ghdxcc8fe1dje5a29acdcxd3dyaw9egqe57bha09ayddcigdedsoechd05ttpjq):
[image]

Another fast tool suggested by @Tezz: http://www.learnsanskrit.org/tools/sanscript

Example:

[image]