# Devanagari script in Hinduism.SE

Tags: feature-request

I have a hell lot of doubts in hindu scriptures. It would be very helpful if there is a devanagari script as most of the scripts are in the same. It would be better if there is an option for transliteration to English for the benifit of the non-understandables of devanagari script

Comment: Visit [Devanagari transliteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devanagari_transliteration). IAST & ITRANS are mostly used translation schemes.

Comment: It was already discussed here. [Please provide transliterations for non-English text in your posts](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/61/3500). If you feel existing answer is not satisfactory, you can provide an answer with your views.