# Allow questions/answers in other languages?

Tags: discussion, languages

I want this site to grow into a place where hindus can ask questions about everyday moral dilemmas and experts will answer quoting and interpreting scripture.

Towards this, it may be needed to support more than one indian languages, or at the very least allow people to ask questions or even provide answers in very poor english.

Comment: And please accept shenshins answer, as thats the correct one so no question of a secondary one

Answer (score 9):

No. [Absolutely not.](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/56/13) If you want that, [propose a new site on Area 51.](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create?category=culture)

> ...or at the very least allow people to ask questions or even provide answers in very poor english.

As long as people are doing their best to write in understandable English, that's good enough. If what a user has written makes enough sense that another, more fluent user can edit it into shape, that suffices.

Answer (score 3):

As shenshin already answered, please don't do so, stick to English language only, why is that so?

Stackexchange sites are open to general public, writing questions or answers in local languages won't help users who don't know that language.

As far as this website goes, we do share some shloka or words written in sanskrit, but that doesn't mean we just mention the sanskrit word and go away, if you write anything in local language, make sure you also write the meaning for that besides the word in English language too for example...

*ओं in Devanagari (Om)*