# Can Indian languages related questions be posted on Hinduism SE?

Tags: discussion, scope

I have proposed SE site for [Indian Languages](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97432/indian-languages)

But sometimes I feel this should be part of **Hinduism SE**.

Help me to understand the scope.

Answer (score 12):

I went through your sample list of questions and these are exactly the type of questions we want to **avoid** on Hinduism.SE:

> - I want to learn Tamil grammar. There are 2 accepted grammar books it seems. What grammar rules should I learn Tolkappiyam or Nannul?
> - Are current Tamil letters derived / evolved from "Vata eluthukal" (வட்டெழுத்துக்கள்)?
> - How can I pronounce the retroflex consonants found in Telugu and many other Indian languages?
> - Where I can find animated tutorial for Kannada?

The reason we want to avoid such questions is, they are out of scope for Hinduism.SE. The scope is very well defined in the [Help Center](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as:

> You've come to the right place if you have questions about:
>
> - **Hindu** scripture and mythology.
> - Academic questions about **Hindu** philosophical thought.
> - Questions about **Hindu** practices.
> - Historical questions about the evolution of **Hinduism**.
> - Different sects of **Hinduism** and their beliefs.

Now you could still ask a language question that is in some way related to **Hinduism** (Hindu culture, Hindu scripture etc.) e.g., if a Kannada scholar incorrectly translated Bhagavad Gita from Sanskrit to Kannada or Kannada to English and you are not sure of the meaning of something, you could ask 'is there a better word in Kannada to convey the meaning?'. However, do keep in mind that this is [primarily an English language website](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/57/2995). We definitely don't want folks writing their questions entirely in Kannada and people answering those in Kannada.

I believe the reason we have decided to allow [sanskrit](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sanskrit) language related questions here is because much of Hindu scripture was written in Sanskrit and then translated to other Indian languages.

It sounds like you want to expand the scope of Hinduism.SE to include all Indian languages, but if we do that, this website will become exceedingly difficult to moderate and also lose its purpose.

So the answer to your question:

> Indian languages related questions can be posted in Hinduism SE?

is **No**.

Comment: I think questions on Sanskrit grammar are off topic for this site. Sanskrit is allowed only to certain extent on this site.