# Is "What scriptures/XYZ say about ...<my off topic query>?", a freeway to convert a Qn to on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions, close-reasons, vote-to-close

There are numerous Qn-s (including few of mine), which starts with,

> "What scriptures/some school/my favorite philosophy/acharyas/XYZ say about [some concept]?"

Many a times these Qns are on-topic, but many a time the Qns are off-topic (IMO). The header merely acts as a "boarding pass" to insert the Qn. Now since, it's asking about scriptures, one can't close it as off-topic or opinion based.
I am sorry, if I am the only one to pedantically see this trend. :-)

**Question**: In what scenario, we should close-vote such Qns when above "boarding pass" is present?

For example, I clearly know that asking below is off-topic:

> Should I travel abroad for studies?

Now, following may appear like on-topic:

> What does Hinduism say about travelling in foreign regions for *Shiksha & Diksha*?

[Probably the above example may be a bad one, as it indeed looks like on-topic. However, there was not much concept about travelling 'too' much outside for studies, so according to me it's still an off-topic Qn, at least borderline.]

Comment: You are not the only one. I have the same idea about this type of question. Some questions fall under off-topic category or not a _good_ question. [This is what](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42747817#42747817) I said just yesterday while having a chat discussion.

Comment: If you can give me some examples (even hypothetical examples) of such questions that you think should be off-topic.  To me, questions of the form “What does Hindu scripture say about X?” may sometimes be low-quality, i.e. they may not evince much research effort, but it seems like most such questions would be on-topic, except when X is some modern topic, like “quantum mechanics”, “the Internet”, “buying life insurance”, etc., in which case it would be closed because any potential answer would be engaged in opinion-based speculation.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, apart from the example I gave in the main Qn, the similar discussions about topics you wrote in the comment -- can be taken as examples. At times, I think "What scriptures say about ..." bypasses the off-topic possibility easily. I also feel that such Qn-s are not easily close-able.

Comment: @iammilind I think the examples I gave are all easily closeable, either under the "scientific speculation" reason" or the "opinion-based" reason.

Comment: Just an [example](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/24306/5212) I found. A primarily opinion based title is changed to is there a mention of..

Comment: Good question! We have been getting some off-topic questions which are made on-topic trickily.

Comment: @iammilind sv's Q is certainly not off-topic, the way it is poised.. it is factual.. but may be unanswerable..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`"What scriptures/XYZ say about ... "` -- should not be the free way to convert an off-topic Qn to on-topic.

The main concern is how to filter such posts?
One simple way to determine such hidden off-topic post is, to read the Qn without the above header. And decide if the Qn is suitable.

Another better but effortful way is that the active users may edit/remove such header line out of the Qn, as our site anyways requires the answers to be backed up with sources.

Comment: Your example Q " What scriptures..... about the subject S?" is off -topic or otherwise depending on the variable S... But determining whether S has been discussed at all in any of the scriptures is not easy... So, i never close Qs (or try to do so) ..because i can't never be sure of..unless they are pretty obvious..

Comment: I agree with what you said in the question and the answer except the last line. The [tag:scripture] should be used for questions which discuss about scriptures only. Adding that tag for every scriptural reference becomes tag abuse. It should not be tagged if there is a word scripture in the question. btw, another example of turning a closed question to on-topic https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9260/5212.

Answer (score 4):

No, it is not...

Between this question- "Should I travel abroad for studies?" and - "What does Hinduism (or Hindu scriptures) say about traveling to foreign lands for the purpose of studying?"--- there isn't any major difference.

When we ask on Hinduism.SE.. parts in the beginning of a question like - "What's the view of Hinduism" or "What do Hindu scriptures say" ... are often understood and so adding them specifically is not of much significance..

So, just by adding those kind of lines in the questions, one can not make his/her "off-topic" question on-topic..

There's one more issue here..

You say "my off-topic query" ..Now how are you so sure that your query is really off-topic?

Suppose a user A has gone through 1% of the scriptures.. Now a question that is off-topic for A may not be so for a user B who has gone through 2% of the scriptures .. He will say wait it's not off-topic..i know where this topic has been discussed.. and so on ..

Therefore only a person who has gone through all the scriptures can decide whether a particular question is really off-topic or not.. leaving a few very obvious cases of course..

Lastly, this issue can not be dealt with generally, we need to deal with **individual questions** .. and i think users here are smart enough to close questions as off-topic which are genuinely so ... although some errors can creep in given the nature of the site and the vastness of Hindu scriptures.

**EDIT:**

Let's take the following question for example.. It will clarify both the points i discussed:

**Is it ok for a student to sleep during the daytime?**

Now, it will obviously fetch some close votes to start with.. but this is not off-topic .. the scriptures provide an answer to this query.

Now, since the question is being asked on HSE, it's understood that OP is asking the following one:

**Is it ok as per Hinduism OR Is it ok as per Hindu scriptures for a student to sleep during the daytime?**

So, this particular question will not be closed as off-topic because it is genuinely not and irrespective of whether or not it has at it's start, lines that are mentioned above..

Also, as already said, it will be good, if you can add to your post, which questions, according to you, remained open just because they are being asked in the particular aforementioned way, and, if they were not been asked in that fashion, would have been closed as off-topic ..

Comment: Of course, such header should not be a free-way to convert off-topic to on-topic; but the Qn comes, how can that be prevented? Now your answer says that, the users are smart enough. But I think the users are also conservative enough to not close such Qn-s. Do you have any example, where *"What does scriptures say about ..."* kind of Qn is closed as off-topic? Though I don't remember any such, it seems extremely rare to have closed such posts.

Comment: If a Q was not closed as off-topic then users must have thought that it is not.. why do u think it was given a free pass just because it contained such a line? also, it's better u add in ur post few such examples.. we can then deal with them specifically..@iammilind

Comment: "Suppose a user A has gone through 1% of the scriptures.." questions closure has nothing to do with the knowledge of scriptures a person knows. It is based on the knowledge of the help center, faq and the policies the site has followed. The knowledge of the scriptures is needed while answering the questions not while closing them as off-topic. They need to know what is personal advice, scientific speculation and what _is the scope_ of our site. Our site has some limits. That is the scope and that should be known not the % of scriptures. The _community_ votes to close not a single A or B.

Comment: "What do Hindu scriptures say" ... are often understood and so adding them specifically is not of much significance.." I say the same in my answer. That line is redundant and adding a tag if one wants scriptural reference. But I have also given examples where that line is misused. Some personal advice questions, non Hinduism questions are turned to on-topic. Another thing I said already, scope is not defined based on the answer. Allowing everything in the scriptures will be a problem because we haven't seen fully. So, we can't close any question with that benefit of doubt. That's the drawback.

Answer (score 3):

Scriptures are oxygen to Hinduism. There are lot of scriptures for Hinduism, which covers wide variety of topics. The **topics covered by Hinduism in detail are assets of Hinduism**.

If the question asked by OP has its answer in Hindu scriptures, then it should be answered. Here many users raise the issue that *how many such topics can be allowed to ask*. Let us be clear here.

Hindu scriptures does not contain any entire subject (say mathematics, geography, horse riding, cooking etc.,). SUB (a subject Physics) is a subject by itself and may have a separate site in stack network. But the SUB covered in Hindu scriptures is an asset or property of Hinduism. So, the questions that target to the SUB inside scriptures should be on topic.

If we do not allow such questions by saying that there are other sites to discuss about them, then the issue is that the other sites of SUB discuss about contemporary SUB, not Hindu SUB (SUB explained in scriptures).

*If we have answer for question in scriptures, then there is no reason to make it off topic.*

Thus, if any question start with *scriptural opinion* or *scriptural reference*, we have to treat them as questions on Hinduism only, not as questions that fall outside Hinduism.

Bottom line is that **Hinduism did not explain total mathematics in its scriptures and hence allow the questions for mathematics inside scriptures.**

Comment: There is [mathematics.se] to post mathematics questions. There is one more site. Mathematics Overflow. One more site like us is not at all useful.

Comment: That mathematics is developed recently and may or may not part of Hinduism. The one in texts is part of Hinduism (which may be named as mathematics later).

Comment: The Q "What Hindu scriptures say about a topic?" can not be off-topic for this site  and it is evident from even common sense. The problem is when that topic is not covered as such in scriptures as then such Qs will remain unanswered but that is not the reason we shd close such Qs. For e.g on a forum on Swami Vivekananda, the Q "What is Vivekananda's opinion on a topic?" is a valid Q to ask. Now, if he had not said anything on that topic then that's the answer.

Comment: @Rickross _The Q "What Hindu scriptures say about a topic?" can not be off-topic for this site and it is evident from even common sense_ if so then what do you say [What is the function of brain according to Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/11374/what-is-the-function-of-brain-according-to-hinduism) ?

Comment: This answer gives many things which are against SE way of functioning. on-topic and off-topic are decided based on question only & not answer. If everything is allowed, there's no purpose of having only one site for Hinduism and it loses its individuality as a religious site. It contradicts all the faq discussions which happened in the past. There would be no off-topic question if chosen based on answering. That's not how it's done. Users here are not expert doctors, scientists to judge content on subjects whether right or wrong. That would affect on long run. It promotes a type of Fanaticism.

Answer (score 0):

Let me introduce myself, and explain why I'm here, first. I'm Tinkeringbell and I moderate both Interpersonal Skills and Meta.SE. I've been discussing this problem/post with one of your moderators in a moderator chatroom, and after reading the answers here, I decided to try and help by writing one of my own, to bring to your attention another approach to this problem.

[This meta post on Christianity SE](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3973/40334) describes how they handle questions about 'What does scripture say about XYZ', and I think this approach may fit this site as well. Now, I must admit I'm more familiar with Christianity than Hinduism (both the StackExchange sites and the religion), but I think sufficient parallels can be drawn here:

**Bad Christianity question:**

> What does the Bible say the age of the earth is?

**Good Christianity question:**

> What's the Biblical basis for a seven day creation and a 6,000-10,000 year old earth?

**Their reasoning:**

> The bottom line is that "What does the Bible say about X" is often a matter of personal interpretation, or opinion.
>
> For many answers that claim "The Bible says X", it is probably fair to expect that you can take some other verse (perhaps out of context) and say "No, the Bibles says Y or Z."

From my discussion with your moderator, I got the impression that the same can be said for Hindu texts. Asking 'What does X say about Y' is probably not the type of question you'd want.

---

#### Is “What scriptures/XYZ say about …< my off-topic query >?”, a free way to convert a Qn to on-topic?

**I would say it's not, and it never should be**. Take the example of Christianity, and don't accept questions that simply ask 'What does scripture say about X?'. Even the Bible has mentions of people sleeping, of people farming, of people hunting... yet questions that ask 'What does the Bible say about sleeping' aren't useful for Christianity SE, as sleeping isn't a 'religious practice' within Christianity.

Instead, **focus on questions where scripture can be used as a source to explain Hinduism, its beliefs and its practices**. This will make your site less prone to being too vulnerable to interpretations and discussions (primarily opinion based), unanswerable questions/questions where the answer is a simple 'there is no scripture on this' and even trolling (really, who doesn't want to know what scripture says about pineapple on pizza and settle the debate forever/turn it into a religious war?).

If you can edit a question to ask 'What text is at the base of this belief/practice', by all means, go for it. But just rephrasing a question to ask 'what does the text say about < something unrelated to Hinduism as a religion >' should be off-topic and bad practice.

Comment: "What's the Biblical basis for a seven day creation and a 6,000-10,000 year old earth?" - this question already assumes Earth was created 10,000 years ago. So you'll immediately find comments questioning that claim, 'where did you read this?', etc. But if you ask 'What does the Bible say the age of the earth is?' you are essentially welcoming different interpretations. 'The bottom line is that "What does the Bible say about X" is often a matter of personal interpretation, or opinion.' – I see no problem with personal interpretation as long as it's backed up with sources.

Answer (score -1):

We had a plenty of discussion already here and the votes to this question and several examples show how this can be misused. To make the mood lighter, let's have a funny story (Sorry for a long answer).

There was a boy studying in a middle school. He was preparing for an elocution competition conducted by his school management. He learned thoroughly about Cow and reached his school. Finally the hour came and the competitions started. After some time, it was his turn. He talked about it clearly. As follows.

> Cow is very useful animal and gives us milk. Milk is considered as the complete and nutritious food. Cow is a domestic and religious animal. It has a large body, four legs, one long tail, two horns, two ear, two eyes, one big nose, one big mouth and one head. It is found in almost every regions of the country. In India, it is ritual and custom to worship Cow. Cow’s milk is used in the pooja, abhisek and other holy purposes. Cow is called by everyone as “Gau Mata” to give her mother like status in the Hindu religion......

The teachers were impressed with this essay. Gave good marks. As a second topic, they asked about "Sky". This made the boy startled. He only prepared for Cow essay. He had no idea about Sky. He thought for a minute and started talking about Sky.

> Sky is what we call a blue appearance above our head. It appears blue in colour. There are many clouds in the sky. Clouds take in water from oceans, rivers and give us rain. If there are heavy rains, there will be greenery. Trees and plants grow. These plants and grass are food for domestic animals like Goat, Buffalo, Cow etc., **Cow is a very useful animal and gives us milk**. Milk is considered  as the complete and nutritious food. Cow is a domestic and religious animal. It has a large body, four legs, one long tail, two horns, two ear, two eyes, one big nose, one big mouth and one head. It is found in almost every regions of the country. In India, it is ritual and custom to worship Cow. Cow’s milk is used in the pooja, abhisek and other holy purposes.........

So, he continued with Cow essay. His teachers *did not* give marks for his second essay. Why? Because he was talking about another topic to bring relation between two different topics.

---

I believe why I said this story now. We are not in a different situation. We received many questions like having "According to Hindu scriptures,", "What to scriptures say about ", "According to Hinduism"... This line has been the entry pass to bypass the off-topic check. It is turning to a [Boat programming meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/14470/357396). Boat programming means a question posted on Stack Overflow which asked what is needed to program on a boat. The reason why it was asked was having the word "Programmers" in the question. It was eventually deleted by Jeff Atwood. Here the word is Hindu scriptures and any question can be made on-topic for the site using them.

Some may ask for examples. I have plenty of them. There was a question about origin of Dravidian languages. To those who don't know, [questions regarding Indian languages are off-topic](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/538/5212) for our site (Not only Indian, any language. No bias). So, I pointed out that such questions are off-topic. After a comment, the OP realized that and self deleted that question. After a month or two, the same user has posted the same question. No change in the topic. It asked the origin of Dravidian languages. But this time, there was modification... yes there is a "What do Hindu scriptures say about origin of Dravidian languages". Voila, that was upvoted. I voted to close it and repeated almost the same comment. The reply was "**What do Hindu Scriptures say**". That comment was upvoted heavily and the reviews were favorable. There were not enough close votes on the question. It was answered too. If we look at both of the questions, there is nothing different. The gist is the same. If there is no phrase 'Hindu scriptures say' in the first question but the question is same. We are a site about Hinduism. Answers posted here are obviously from Hinduism point of view only ([That is why the tag hindus was blacklisted](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/147/5212)). So, even if there is no mention of "Hinduism" or "scriptures" in the question, the answers will be the same. I do not see any difference between two variations. That will be the same. It will be off-topic only.

There is another type of modifying a question. We know that dream questions and personal advice questions are off-topic for our site. There was a question posted about asking how to interpret dead relatives in a dream and had details of that specific dream. That was closed as off-topic (with a mod intervention. I tried to reopen after editing but it failed). That was fine. After an year or two, there was another question asking the same i.e.,  But there is a modification in the question. The OP added a paragraph where dreams are discussed in Hinduism and gave an introductory passage of importance of dreams in Hinduism. (OP has some knowledge of Hinduism and a high rep user) The question is not closed as off-topic. That is open (reviewers chose to leave it open. Mod intervened again). If we remove that passage and look at the topic, that is asking about dream interpretation only. There are some questions which were made on-topic in this way. Irony is  The question is not changed but there was a passage explaining their role in Hinduism. I don't think that makes a difference. Let us see how. For example, I have a question about horse riding.

> Horse riding is a skill and one of the 64 sciences. This was taught to people in ancient India. Lord Krishna and Balarama learnt these skills in 64 days. Horse riding played a major role in Mahabharata war. Horses also have an importance in Hinduism. Lord Surya turned to a horse and beget Ashvini devatas. Nakula was a master in taming horses.
>
> So, my question is **According to Hindu scriptures**, how to master horse riding? How to tame horses? Is there a text explaining this (which was taught in the ancient times)?
>
> tags : [scripture](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripture) [animals](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animals)

So, is this a question about Hinduism and on-topic for us? If we remove that paragraph, that is definitely off-topic. The gist is learning about horse taming which is not a religious question. So, this should make clear. Same question if asked without that passage, that would be closed immediately. But the above question will be opened. That would also give place to bias based on reputation. The question not given importance but the word like Hindu scriptures is given importance. People who are not well versed with those topics have more probability of getting closed. So, there will be a bias which is a dangerous situation to handle.

This trend of making blatantly off-topic questions into on-topic by adding "Hindu scriptures" is a dangerous. Unfortunately, this is mostly done by users with access to moderator tools (names not required). That would definitely add a bad name to the site's reputation. There can be many variations like this. There can be 'n' number of questions about non Hinduism topics added with scriptural reference. It has reached to a state where users started advising to add the line to stay away from review queues.

[image: Blatantly off-topic question advised to add scriptural reference]

> Shiv Bhagvan ki mahanta koi Khuda nahi janta. Nearly everyone knows this. Like if you agree.

I don't know if the user said without knowing the help center and scope. But see the upvotes question and comment got! this raises question on the guidance we are giving to new users. Need to take care.

These are types of statements on social media which say "Like and RT if you agree." That too written in Non-English. Such questions are [clearly off-topic](/help/dont-ask) for Stack Exchange. I have even received comments that it will be a valid question if "What do Hindu scriptures say" is added. It supports my statement that closeable and off-topic questions (like personal advice, scientific speculation, hypothetical) are converted into on-topic by adding that statement.

### So, the question arises, why is it off-topic to ask a matter which is present in Hinduism books?

This is a valid question. But there is a huge disadvantage if *everything* present in Hindu texts is allowed. **Hindu texts and sages talk about a wide range of topics almost everything**. There is a mention of gravity, speed of light, rainbows, music, pets, cooking, public speaking, language, pleasing women (!) and [so on](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/24851/5212). In the Brahma purana, there are chapters dedicated to water cycle. In the *Brahmanda Purana*, birth of animals is discussed. In the Narada Purana, there are chapters discussing music, mathematics. There are varied texts on different topics. **By using some lines and sentences, we can easily bring relation between Hinduism and any non religious topic. IN other words we can manipulate. If we encourage questions based on the mention in the texts, then there is nothing off-topic for our site**. The off-topic section from the help center can just be deleted. It is because Hindu texts talk about each and everything. So, going by that logic, we should allow questions about music, dance, mathematics, physics, chemistry, Cooking and all. We will turn into a site which accepts almost everything. So, that would make us a site of everything. This would only increase questions per day but those are not good questions as it also defeats the purpose of Stack Exchange to have a different sites to deal with different topics. It doesn't take much time to fill the site's questions with non religious questions with scriptural references. That would decrease quality. We should not to forget to [**Focus on quality**](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/92/5212).

If someone wants to have food, they should go to a restaurant not a movie theatre. This movie theatre owner may sell rice which he has but it is not a right way to recommend movie theatre to get food. Same applies here too. Same was said by Mad Scientist in their [answer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/292/5212) to [Users asking for scientific answers / reasons](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/142/5212)

So, the solution we have is to allow questions which asks for scriptural reference of some belief or a practice (we do that and many questions are present already) and not references of some Non religious topics like environment, physics, cooking, dice etc., 
If a question is posted about "Scriptural reference about ". This 'X topic' should be a religious topic and not a scientific or other. If a question is asking scriptural reference **about** , then the question itself is about that topic. If there is a better site which answers better, we can also migrate.

Comment: "That would definitely add a bad name to the site's reputation" - how does it bring bad name to the site? Or is this just your assumption? Do you have any "bad name" stats? How do you know posts promoting astrology or cow urine are not the ones bringing bad name to the site?

Comment: @sv. It is not my assumption. If high rep users are the ones who are adding sentences and then changing blatantly off-topic to on-topic questions. Imagine question about horse riding, feeding pets, physics etc., are posted on the site and answers giving answers far from reality. Questions about anatomy and answers giving wrong number of bones and nerves. Our site questions show up in google very quickly. Then the site loses its name giving accurate answers. I have some outside SE examples of site not having a good name. Other SE sites were trolled for asking non-practical questions. 1/2

Comment: Our site answers are also trolled on Twitter. We would also face the same result. Asking questions far from reality and impractical questions which are not religious would give us a bad name. There was one such question was also asked on Meta SE. It was downvoted but the effect is shown.Regarding cow urine, I will not recommended to follow 1000 year old texts instructions. Because cows of that time and today are different. Even though we are a religious site, we should think rationally and practically. These are observed by outside rational world. We should think of today's religion also.  2/2

Comment: "Same was said by Mad Scientist in their answer to Users asking for scientific answers / reasons" - You may have misunderstood [the answer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/292): "**Any answer has to be from a doctrinal point of view**, scientific answers are not allowed, and questions that ask for scientific answers are closed." -- asking for science present in Hindu scripture i.e., the Hindu point of view is not the same as 'scientific answers'. Recently there was an answer on astrology/astronomy with zero references from Hindu scripture. It's those answers that should be disallowed

Comment: "Regarding cow urine, I will not recommended to follow 1000 year old texts instructions. Because cows of that time and today are different." - what about the rest of the world? Should the user add a disclaimer - 'this is what the scripture says, but please don't try this at home'? I'm saying let's not get into this 'brings bad name' thing. What you think will bring good name may bring a bad name IMO. Objective questions have objective answers.

Comment: Whether horse-riding instructions are present in Hindu scripture is an objective question. It is not off-topic. It doesn't bring any bad name. If you think it does, downvote, but don't close as off-topic.

Comment: @sv. No. I was talking about word about having users with no expertise judging the content posted on science and other subjects and allowing doctrinal and religious questions. If some question about anatomy is asked and HIndu text gives a wrong answer, that will be upvoted. Asking science in Hinduism will not be useful because there can be any number of scientific questions with "Hindu scriptures" before it. So, that would require some expertise in answering. That would give rise to copy paste. Anyway both Q&A involving science is off-topic now. That may change in future. Who knows.

Comment: @sv. "It is not off-topic. It doesn't bring any bad name". So, if someone is suffering from fever, do you recommend going to a barber who knows curing fever or a certified doctor? There are other sites which answer better on cooking, swimming, health, horse riding. Hindu texts talk about horse riding as ancient Hindus know about it and were taught in schools. They also contain how to please women. Should we allow those questions too? Regarding bad name, we won't get effected if we stick to religion and not go to topics like science, space, planets. Think practically. We are a religious site.

Comment: 'users with no expertise judging the content posted on science and other subjects' - that's for users to worry about. Why should you bother? If some users start drinking cow urine following a highly upvoted answer, who's stopping them? Why do you care about one and not the other?

Comment: The reason we don't allow purely scientific answers is that this site lacks such users. And this is not the site meant for those answers/discussions. Trying to find science in Hindu scripture is different. I think you are attempting to mix both. Strictly speaking questions such as '[Rahu and Ketu in planetary location](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/7098)' should be disallowed. But it can be allowed provided the answers stick to Hindu references.

Comment: @sv. I am bothering because the platform posted is the site I participate. Out of curiosity and interest, I am looking for improvement of the site. Some people do take answers literally. That is the problem. I am caring about everyone. That is why I took time and wrote this answer. Trying to find science is interpreted differently by people here. For them, ancient science is different. Questions on Math, physics can be asked with the "What do hindu..." before it and bring science in the site. That would give rise to scientific explanation in the answers again. That is what I am opposed to.

Comment: "That would give rise to scientific explanation in the answers again. That is what I am opposed to." - then the focus should be on the answers which don't cite Hindu scripture, are speculative or cite some science paper. No need to attack the question. Adding 'What do Hindu scriptures say about...' is simply reminding users: 'Do not engage in scientific speculation. I just need the Hindu point of view.'

Comment: @sv. You don't seem to understand. Asking off-topic questions in the guise of What do scriptures say. This is the whole point. Don't pick a single sentence and write comment.Hindu point of view of Bigbang theory, Newton's laws Hondu POV of swimming, Hindu POV of flirting with women these would be the questions we get. Not related to religion but the tag will be the same according to Hinduism. Hindus swim just like any other, they ride horse like other look at Boat meme I linked in the answer.

Comment: The latest example you posted if framed as 'Do any scriptures consider Shiva as the greatest god that there is?' is again a perfectly valid question. The recommendation in the comment is meant for OP to remove 'Do you agree with this or not?' and turn it into an objective question based on scriptures.

Comment: 'You don't seem to understand.' - ha ha, while others think it's you who sees every other question which begins with 'What do Hindu scriptures say about...' as "blatantly off-topic"...so let's leave it at that.

Comment: @sv. Either you didn't my answer completely or the people who think that I am opposing every question starting with "What do Hindu..." didn't read my answer completely. Or both. I stated that questions about religion are very welcome in the last paragraph. I am opposed to lines addition to dice games, science, martial arts, personal advice questions and posting as religious question. I am not the one who think like that. There are many people who thought the same including OP of this meta question.

Comment: When someone thought dice games and horse riding are on-topic, what else is not on-topic? XD There was no question in the example I added. He just made a claim and asking to vote like fanatic  forums and Social Media. We are neither of them. OP is determined that Shiva is the greatest God and asking to vote if they agree. Where's the question? The suggestion should be asking to post objective questions and not adding "Hindu scriptures.." in the question. We need not to put words in the OP's mouth. Still that question is against "Thou shall promote No God". Let's leave if you don't understand.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I think this particular topic should be discussed in separate chat-room. How about converting this conversation to chat-room and having this topic discussed at there?

Comment: @Pandya No. We have more than enough chat rooms already. I am clarifying the doubts raised by user here. This is not a chatty conversation.

Comment: The first on-topic point read as "You've come to the right place if you have questions about: **Hindu scripture** and mythology." So, what area should be considered for scripture according to you?

Comment: @Pandya I know the scope. I'm not saying we should remove it. What is a scriptural question - I answered it many times. https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/891/5212 and https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1191/5212 . That applies to [tag:scripture] too. A question which contains word "scripture" is not enough to tag it with scripture tag and can't be called a question about scripture. If one posts What do scriptures say about Sati, it's about practice. If one asks about porn, it's a belief and not scripture. But many add out of feelings & faith . More drama if it's corrected.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85817/discussion-on-answer-by-sarvabhouma-is-what-scriptures-xyz-say-about-my-off).

Comment: Now, I have read it overall and seems covering good points. Agree that, off-topic points are easily convertible if the users use certain phrase or tags in the questions. BTW, You may want to add a "tl;dr". Some part of the answer is too detailed to be able to keep the momentum.  :-) Those parts can be removed, shortened or put at the bottom.