HSE Editing Best Practices - Question edited to Hindi language
I noticed a question whose title had been edited to Hindi and changed it back to English.
Wanted to bring this to attention as I'm not sure what was the intent of that edit.
If there're any best practices to editing for HSE, kindly share them.


It should definitely have stayed in English. See https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56/what-are-the-allowed-languages-for-questions-comments-or-answers-here
